# Error BAD_INPUT_ERROR producción PayPal

Tags: php, formularios, paypal

Intentando integrar mis pagos de Paypal al pasar a producción me da un error de BAD_INPUT_ERROR pero las pruebas en el sandbox me funcionan con el mismo formulario.

El formulario que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypalForm" id="paypalForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="input" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="input" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="input" name="business" value="cuenta_api1.mitienda.com">
    <input type="input" name="rm" value="2"><!-- devolucion por post = 2 -->
    <input type="input" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="input" name="return" value="http://mitienda.com/finalizado">
    <input type="input" name="cancel_return" value="http://mitienda.com/cancela">
    <input type="input" name="shipping_1" value="4.9500">        
    <input type="input" name="invoice" value="0503172317">
    <input type="input" name="charset" value="UTF-8">
    <input type="input" name="notify_url" value="http://mitienda.com/paypal/ipn-call.php">
    <input type="input" name="item_number_1" value="1901">
    <input type="input" name="item_name_1" value="Examplenombre">
    <input type="input" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    <input type="input" name="amount_1" value="9.08">
    <input type="input" name="item_number_2" value="1352">
    <input type="input" name="item_name_2" value="Example-nombre 2">
    <input type="input" name="quantity_2" value="1">
    <input type="input" name="amount_2" value="19.85">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" target="_blank"/>
</form>
```

En Sandbox ya os digo, me funciona pero al pasar a entorno Producción es cuando me muestra el error.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado...
Se ve que (aunque no lo he encontrado en la documentación por ningún sitio) en vez del dato de la API hay que poner la dirección de email en el parámetro business